# Express looks for views folder based on where Node is run from

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

My folder structure is like this:

```
-server
--index.js
--core
---controllers
----maincontroller.js
---app.js
---router.js
--public
---views
----pages
-----index.ejs
```

I have the app.js like so:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const routes = require('./router')

const app = express()

app.use('/', routes)

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/../public/views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

module.exports = app
```

Where I set the 'views' folder to be one folder up from the 'core' folder, then /public/views.

Then I start my server by running `node index.js` in the server folder. The `index.js` file looks like this:

```
const app = require('./core/app');
const http = require('http').Server(app)

console.log(app.get('views'));

http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, '0.0.0.0', function(){
    console.log('listening on :3000')
})
```

However, when I try to get the `index.ejs`, i get the error:

`Error: Failed to lookup view "../views/pages/index.ejs" in views directory "/home/myUser/server/views"`

If I run `node ../index.js` from my /core/ folder, the error changes to:

`Error: Failed to lookup view "../views/pages/index.ejs" in views directory "/home/myUser/server/core/views"`

and if I run the same command from the /public/ folder, it works. What gives?

I'll also add that the `console.log()` in `index.js` logs the correct file path...

Comment: try doing this `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../public/views'))`.

Comment: Same error sadly.

Comment: What does `console.log(app.get('views'));` give you, and which node / express versions are you using?

Comment: The console log, logs ``/home/myUser/server/public/views``. The node version I'm running is 6.11.5. You think me, forgetting to update Node for an eternity could be the reason why? Express is listed as express@4.16.2

Comment: I just updated Node to v9.2.0 but still getting the same error, with it looking for a /views/ folder from the directory where the node command is run from.

Comment: Don't think this is Node-related, your absolute views path is fine. But express seems to completely ignore it (the `'views'` setting) and rather uses its default behavior (using `process.cwd()` and adding `/views`). How exactly do you render your _index.ejs_ view?

Comment: Hmm, I got it working actually.

I followed along on this tutorial initally: https://youtu.be/L5Nle1VXYnw for the first 10 minutes or so, just to get an idea of how to seperate the logic and how to split the files.
In the video, he uses a router.js file where he declares `routes = express()`, and `routes.get('/', controller.get)`. The controller is imported from a basicController.js file, where he renders the function.

Bypassing the router.js file, and calling ``app.get('/', controller.get)`` from app.js seems to have fixed it. I suspect it's because of where router.js was located